# How to perfect align rotation?

Tags: rendering

How can i align the rotation of two objects perfectly?

I have this cylinder between two blocks and i want to perfect align the piston end (orange) to the cylinder (rotation).

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You first need to correctly realign the object's orientation.

To realign the object orientation with its face orientation, select a face of your object in *Edit* mode, create a custom orientation in the *Transform Orientations* panel:

[image]

In the *Options* panel (top right of 3D view) activate *Transform > Affect Only > Origins*:

[image]

In the header menu click on *Object > Transform > Align To Transform Orientation*:

[image]

Deactivate *Only Origins*, do an <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>, now your cylinder is aligned with the *Global* orientation again, it should be easy to align with the other cylinder.

Comment: maybe i am too dumb...but this aligns the position, right? i want to align the rotation....just for info: i have applied the "wrong" rotation already, so i want to correct that :(

Comment: i think this would have been my solution, if i hadn't applied my rotation :( but i have, so i tried and this didn't help me unfortunately....

Comment: it looks like this command just copies the values of the rotation....if i understood it right

Comment: you've applied the orientation of what object?

Comment: for the orange object, which has not "perfect" 0 degrees. But it shows of course 0 degrees in the properties, because i applied it.

Comment: i am not sure, maybe it works with snap - align rotation to target? this sounds good, but i don't know how to use it

Comment: even the snap tool just works, if the cube's rotation is not applied ...so if you apply a rotation, you are lost forever :(

Comment: I've edited, you can align back the orientation of your object with the global orientation, once done you're good I guess?

Comment: ok, with your text i  was too dumb, but with your pictures, i got it. Thank you very much!!!!! you saved me!!!